# Clone form fields with jQuery and increment 'id' and 'for' attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, clone

I'm looking at creating an RSVP form:

http://adrianandemma.com/

The form contains a guest name and a radio button for yes/no.

I have added an option to 'add further guest' which clones the name filed and the radio buttons, but they are keeping the same id's and for attributes, so the radio buttons in particular are getting messed up!

Is there a way than once I clone the name and radio fields I could also amend the id and for elements also?

Perhaps have the initial fields as id="guest1" and radios for="guest1-yes"/for="guest1-no" and then have these increment each time they are cloned?

Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-row guest">
   <div class="field-l">
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
   </div>
   <div class="field-r">
      <input type="radio" name="coming" id="coming-yes" value="Yes" required><label for="coming-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="coming" id="coming-no" value="No"><label for="coming-no">No</label>
   </div>
</div>
<a class="addguest" href="#">Add further guest</a>
```

jQuery:

```
   $('.addguest').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.guest').first().clone().find("input").val('').end().insertBefore(this);
   });
```

and here's how it's laid out:

[image]

Any help would be great, as I've looked for similar questions, but can't get anything to work!

Comment: Is there really any reason to use an ID? The only use case is when you want to bind a `<label>` element to the input, which in your case is not used.

Comment: Wrap the relevan `<input>` element inside its appropriate `<label>` and both the `for` and `id` properties are no longer required. Which makes things somewhat easier.

Comment: I haven't wrapped the radios in the labels, as i'm hiding the radios at present and styling up the labels to look like buttons using this CSS (.field-r input[type="radio"]:checked+label { border: 1px solid #363e3f; }) which relies of the label following the radios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to increment the IDs and FORs of your input and label fields you can use:

[.attr( attributeName, function )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

In your css you need to change from:

```
.field-r input[type="radio"]#coming-yes+label {
   cursor: url('/assets/images/happy.png'), pointer;    
}
.field-r input[type="radio"]#coming-no+label {
   cursor: url('/assets/images/sad.png'), pointer;  
}
```

To:

```
.field-r input[type="radio"].coming-yesRadio+label {
    cursor: url('/assets/images/happy.png'), pointer;
}
.field-r input[type="radio"]..coming-noRadio+label {
    cursor: url('/assets/images/sad.png'), pointer;
}
```

Instead to address each element by id in your CSS you may use a class. That means to add the corresponding class to your input elements.

The snippet:

```js
$('.addguest').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //
    // get the current number of ele and increment it
    //
    var i = $('.guest').length + 1;
    $('.guest').first().clone().find("input").attr('id', function(idx, attrVal) {
        return attrVal + i;  // change the id
    }).attr('name', function(idx, attrVal) {
        return attrVal + i;  // change the name
    }).val('').removeAttr('checked').end().find('label').attr('for', function(idx, attrVal) {
        return attrVal + i; // change the for
    }).end().insertBefore(this);
});
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dk_vermilionregular';
    src: url('http://adrianandemma.com/assets/fonts/dk_vermilion-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('http://adrianandemma.com/assets/fonts/dk_vermilion-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
* {
    font-weight:normal;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family:'dk_vermilionregular', arial, sans-serif;
}
body {
    font-family:'dk_vermilionregular', arial, sans-serif;
    color:#363e3f;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.box {
    text-align:center;
    max-width: 60%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font-size:86px;
    margin:0.5em 0;
}
h1 span {
    display:block;
    font-size: 40px;
}
h2 {
    font-size:68px;
    margin:0.5em 0;
}
p {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin:0.5em 0;
}
a {
    color: #363e3f;
}

a.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:24px;
    color:#363e3f;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding:12px 20px 8px;
    border:1px solid #363e3f;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
}

/*** Images ***/
img {
    max-width:100%;
}
img.ae {
    width:260px;
}
img.ceremony {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 0 20px;
}

/*** Forms ***/
#rsvp {
    z-index: 110;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.form-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

form {
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 60%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

form p {
    font-size:24px;
    margin: 0;
}

.form-row {
    overflow: auto;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}

.field-l {
    float:left;
    width: 70%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.field-r {
    float:right;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: default;
}

.field-l input {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-shadow: none;
    border:1px solid #363e3f;
}

.field-r label {
    font-size:20px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 40%;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.field-r input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    border: 1px solid #363e3f;
}

.field-r input[type="radio"].coming-yesRadio+label {
    cursor: url('http://adrianandemma.com/assets/images/happy.png'), pointer;
}
.field-r input[type="radio"].coming-nosRadio+label {
    cursor: url('http://adrianandemma.com/assets/images/sad.png'), pointer;
}

.field-r input {
    width: 0;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    cursor: default;
}

form button {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #363e3f;
    background: #fff;
    margin:30px 0 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px 0 7px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

form button:hover {
    background: #fcfcfc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-row guest">
    <div class="field-l">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="field-r">
        <input type="radio" name="coming" class="coming-yesRadio" id="coming-yes" value="Yes" required><label for="coming-yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="coming" class="coming-yesRadio" id="coming-no" value="No"><label for="coming-no">No</label>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="addguest" href="#">Add further guest</a>
```

Comment: This looks great thanks! I was still having some issues with the radios, i think due to the cloned radios having the same name attribute. If I add the following to the jQuery code its looks to be working:}).val('').end().find('input').attr('name', function(idx, attrVal) {
   return attrVal + i; // change the name

Comment: I've also added in  .prop('checked',false)  to clear the radio checked status when cloning. Does this look OK?

Comment: OK I removed  .prop('checked',false)  which did actually seem to work and replaced with  .removeAttr('checked').  and this also works. Is this second option a better way of doing it?

Comment: OK great thanks, now I just need to work out how to hook up a simple mail function to send the submissions.

Comment: I'm having issues with the radios buttons on this still and just thought I'd check if you have any suggestions. I am trying to pull the data from any cloned radio buttons and send this via an email to myself. This works fine for the 'name' inputs fields, but not for the radios. If I give the radios a name of coming[], Then it turns out each cloned radio group has the same name, so I cant have multiple selections. Would the answer be to try and amend each cloned radio name attribute to coming[0], coming[1], coming[2] via JS so they all have unique name attributes?

Comment: Not sure if this makes sense, but I tried explaining it in a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437988/losing-radio-values-on-jquery-cloned-form-fields

Comment: @ade123 If with this js code the names are .., coming3, coming4, ... you must take those params with php $_POST['coming' + $i] and not $_POST['coming'][$i].

Comment: I tried just changing out $_POST['coming'][$i] with $_POST['coming' + $i] and it didn't seem to be pulling through any radio values at all to the email script. I I can amend my JS code to update each new radio 'name' to be coming[0],coming[1],coming[2], should I then be able to loop through them in the same way as I currently do with my name inputs? It's just this should also hopefully fix the issue with the cloned radios all having the same name, so only one can be selected at any one time. Struggling here to get anything to work :(

Comment: I managed to get the name attribute to update to coming[1], coming[2], coming[3], etc but I'm still receiving no values at all now for the checked radios. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

HTML

```
<div class="form-row guest">
<div class="field-l">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="guest1" required />
</div>
<div class="field-r">
  <input type="radio" name="coming" id="guest1-yes" value="Yes" required><label for="coming-yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="coming" id="guest1-no" value="No"><label for="coming-no">No</label>
</div>
</div>
<a class="addguest" href="#">Add further guest</a>
```

Jquery

```
var cloneIndex = $(".guest").length;
$('.addguest').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  cloneIndex++;
  $('.guest').first().clone()
    .find("input")
    .attr("id", "guest" +  cloneIndex)   
    .val('').end()  
    .find('input:radio').each(function(idx) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      if(idx % 2 == 0){
        id += "-yes";
      } else {    
        id += "-no";
      }
      $(this).attr('id',id);
    })  
    .val('').end()   
    .insertBefore(this);
});
```

Here is working jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/y392jey4/2/

I think it should helps you,

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it still appears to be having issues with the radio buttons.

Comment: wht kind of issues

Comment: Thanks for this, but the solution outlined by gaetanoM seems to do the job. I can still only check one radio on the example above, but this may bee that issue with the radios having the same name attribute. I've added some code to update the name attribute on radios also.